# Actually my thought got stuck into a very curious question that what happen if we pass 1electron charge through a parallel combination of resistors?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, conservation-laws

Idea of conservation of charge ;division of charge in parallel combination ;smallest magnitude of charge that is of 1electron charge.and somewhat imagination.

Comment: Electronic version of the double-slit diffraction experiment. There may be interesting experimental phenomena which indicate wave-particle duality.

Comment: @Troll Mos Those resistors will also have electrons in them. So the single electron will push on those electrons..

Answer (score 1):

This is a little different than the double slit experiment. You don't have to think of the electron as a wave to see how current goes through multiple resistors.

Let's start simple. You have an isolated wire. The wire is uncharged. There are equal numbers of electrons and protons.

You push an electron on. Now the wire has a net charge. Electrons are free to move. They repel each other. All the electrons shuffle a bit. They are slightly more crowded than the protons. So a small negative charge is spread over the whole wire. The wire is the source of a small electric field.

Now put the wire in a circuit. Push 1 electron into the wire. A pulse of crowdedness propagates down the wire like a pulses of compression propagating down a spring. Very soon it arrives at the other end. 1 electron is pushed out of the wire.

Now make a circuit with parallel resistors. Whenever the pulse comes to a junction where a wire splits, the pulse splits and travels down both wires. Whenever two wires join, pulses arrive from each wire and continue onward.

At the end, the electrons become crowded enough to push 1 electron out of the wire. You can imagine that some paths are longer than others, so pulses do not arrive all at the same time. So perhaps there is a time where electrons are crowded enough to push an electron partially out of the wire and into whatever comes next.

Of course, electrons are not sitting still. Thermal motion motion makes them bounce around inside the wire. So it is only in an average sense that you can say that an electron is partially pushed out.

Also this neglects quantum mechanics. The uncertainty principle limits how precisely you can say that a trajectory exists for an electron. Particularly in a metal, where conduction electrons are in states spread out over many atoms. Again, it is only in an average sense that you can say where electrons are.